# how to show the single alert message for multiple mysql queries?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

i have a small doubt.. i posted my delete.php page coding here.

```
if(isset($_GET["id"]))
{
    $meal_query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM ebmealplans WHERE MealPlanID = '$id'");
    echo mysql_error();
    $room_query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM ebroomtypes WHERE RoomTypeID = '$id'");
    echo mysql_error();
    $tariff_query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM ebvouchertariffs WHERE VoucherID_Fk = '$id'");
    echo mysql_error();
    $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM ebvouchers WHERE VoucherID = '$id'");
    echo mysql_error();
    if($query)
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Voucher deleted successfully'); </script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Failed to delete this voucher'); </script>";
    }
    mysql_close($link);
    echo "<script> location.href='managevouchers.php'; </script>";
}
```

here i am delete some user datas using this php coding. it worked perfectly. i created four separate tables for store the records. if deletion function was successfully completed i want to show the alert message to users "Deleted Successfully". you can see in my coding i'm just show the alert message for only one `$query`. i tried another method..

```
if($query)
{
 alert function
}
else
{
 alert function
}
if($meal_query)
{
 alert function
}
else
{
 alert function
}
if($room_query)
{
 alert function
}
else
{
 alert function
}
if($tariff_query)
{
 alert function
}
else
{
 alert function
}
```

it show the alert message four times. i know multiple alert functions annoying the users. my question is how to show the single alert message for mysql multiple queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the msg pieces in some variable, and alert them all finally.

```
$msgs = array ();

if ($query) {
    $msgs [] = '.....';
} else {
    $msgs [] = '...';
}

if ($meal_query) {
    $msgs [] = '....';
} else {
    $msgs [] = '...';
}
//....


if ($msgs) {
    //join the msgs with line break
    $alert = join ( "\n", $msgs );

    //json encode will make sure it's like "..string..", no quotes problem
    echo '<script> alert(', json_encode ( $alert ), '); </script>';
}
```